# How do I share data between 3 separate authenticated users in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Each of the 3 users will need to read and write the data.

I've looked at other stackoverflow posts, but none seem to answer this question.

For this sharing scheme, I'm also wondering what the Firestore security rules should look like.

Comment: You won't find any answers because the question is far too broad. If you have a Firebase and there are three authenticated users they can all 'share' the data that's in the Firebase - they can all read and all write. So... security rules? If you want all the three users to share data then leave the rules at their default. There are literally 1000 different options but SO is for coding specific issues, not app design issues as there's just no way for us to help without understanding the entire use case. So, attempt some code and when you get stuck, post it, and we'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

You can store an array in that document containing UIDs of those 3 users. For example lets call it "authorized_users".

```
{
  ...otherDocumentFields,
  authorized_users: ["uid1", "uid2", "uid3"]
}
```

You can use the following security rules so only those 3 users can read/write on that document:

```
match /collection/{docID} {
    allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid in resource.data.authorized_users;
}
```